# iPad iOS6 built-in Notes app - where are the notes stored?

Tags: ipad, notes.app

I was thinking about migrating a majority of my text-based notes from Evernote to the built-in Notes app.  Evernote wants 4.99 a month to store off-line notebooks on your mobil e device.  I currently use a Macbook Air but was thinking about consolidating my notes onto my iPad so I'm not referencing two devices.

But I don't want old notes that were sync'd to the application to disappear or somehow be lost to me.

Are the notes stored locally? Is there a limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notes are stored locally without limit other than storage space on the iOS device. They [sync to iCloud](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH2591) and there is a web app for viewing / editing the notes.

They do count towards your 5 GB of free iCloud storage that you get by virtue of operating an iOS device. Should you need more storage than that, you can pay yearly.

If you don't sync the notes to the cloud, then that limit is not in effect. Whether or not you sync with iCloud, the notes are stored locally on the iPad.

Comment: If you choose to migrate, you might use a Mac or computer that has both the Evernote app and notes syncing for iCloud as it's much easier to export/import things that way.

Comment: I was thinking about moving it over using my Mac and then sync'ing it, but I have thousands of notes (I use search extensively).  The main reason why I worry about the limits is because of how Mail acts (it only keeps the last 50 and requires an internet connection to access the rest).

Comment: Notes are basically mail messages - but optimized to give you all of them - not a window to the latest with a hook into searching the rest on the server. You don't list hoe many notes, how many characters and whether it's just text, styled text or rich text documents, but the cost to moving to notes is only your time.